# Set default owner / permission to new files on Linux

Tags: java, linux, chmod, chown, debian-based

I have different .jar files that create a directory with files inside, the problem is that this directory and these files are created with the wrong owner (**root**) and I'd like that by default the owner is **admin**. Is there any use of chmod or chown to change this?

The owner of the directory and files change with some command and thus not be granting permissions each time a file generated by a .jar is created.

I tried to use chmod g+rwxs /dirname but it doesn't work ...

Comment: This could be a symptom of running code with unnecessarily elevated privileges. Can you run it as `admin`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for your reply.
I already ran the code as admin instead of root, it didn't work.

Comment: @Ricardo How were you able to tell that it didn’t work?